# How do you work around the issue of long load time for initial load of an application

Tags: xpages

When no users have the any pages in an application open, it will unload the application from the server after a while.

When a user loads a page in the app after it's been unloaded, it can take quite a while to load.

The simplest way to work around the issue is to have an agent that polls a page in the application each morning before any users are online. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starting with Notes and Domino 8.5.3, you can use the following ini parameters:

**XPagesPreload=1**

Preloads XPages java code at server startup so that they are already in memory when a user access an xpages app for the first time.

**XPagesPreloadDB=servername!!path/mydb.nsf/myxpage.xsp,servername!!path/anotherdb.nsf**

Preloads XPages engine for a specific XPage in a specific database or for all XPages in a database.

Both parameters can be used on the Domino Server and on the Notes client.

As far as I know, the application will be kept in memory even if no user doe access it.

Comment: No, it is also for XPINC. Both parameters can be used on the Domino Server and on the Notes client.