# Instantiate applicationScope bean when Domino server loads

Tags: jsf, xpages, lotus-domino

How do we do this in Domino:

--FROM JSF 2--

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
```

I want to load my applicationScope bean at the start of the server, rather than tie it to a web page.

Comment: Was asked and answered before:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101033/how-do-you-work-around-the-issue-of-long-load-time-for-initial-load-of-an-applic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add 2 notes.ini parameters. One to enable xpages preload and one to specify the nsf to load. Can be more than one. Has been asked before

[How do you work around the issue of long load time for initial load of an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101033/how-do-you-work-around-the-issue-of-long-load-time-for-initial-load-of-an-applic)

Comment: Yes but this will pre-load all my Java code in the whole database and that's growing in size as we move more and more towards Java, I would just like to preload my applicationScope beans not everything. Is that possible at all?

Comment: You can use the agent method described in the link,  but then you need to sort out security. Buying some ram might be easier

Comment: Okay so that's a work-around - it's not a true load this applicationScope bean at startup solution. Normally people use Servlets to do this I believe in JSF 1.1 I believe where these type of annotations are not supported. We are actually initialising this by code as a work-around and we have a if statement to check whether it's loaded each time before we load that applicationScope bean which is not tied to any xpage.

Comment: That's actually standard practice: check if the stuff is there, if not load it.

Comment: Agreed, although JSF 2 would have been great here.